# Spring cloud kafka binder query

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have a requirement where we are consuming messages from one topic then there is some enrichment happening and then we are publishing the message to another topic. below are the events

1. Consumer - Consume the message
2. Enrichment - Enriched the consumed message
3. Producer - Published Enriched message to other topic

I am using Spring cloud kafka binder and things are working fine. suddenly we observed that producer is sending duplicate message to the topic and then we made Producer is idempotent. We have autocommitOffSet to false for better control. Below is what we are doing in the method

```
@StreamListener("INPUT")
@SendTo("OUTPUT")
public void consumer(Message message){
    String inputMessage = message.getPayload.toString();
    String enrichMessage = // Enrichment on inputMessage
    return enrichMessage;
}
```

We observed if ack.acknowledge() failed due to some issue, Message still sent to the outbound channel. How can we handle entire consumer/producer as part of one transaction so that if acknowledge fail message will not sent to the topic.
I have set below transaction properties as well

1. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix=TX-
2. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.configuration.ack=all
3. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.configuration.retries=1
4. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=true
5. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq=true
6. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqName=error.topic
7. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOnError=true

If there is any example available that would be really helpful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the binder transactional. See the documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties

> **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix**

> Enables transactions in the binder. See transaction.id in the Kafka documentation and Transactions in the spring-kafka documentation. When transactions are enabled, individual producer properties are ignored and all producers use the spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.* properties.

> Default null (no transactions)

Note that consumers on the output topic must be configured with `isolation.level=read_committed` to avoid receiving rolled-back records.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I did included below 3 properties "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix","spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.configuration.ack=all","spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.configuration.retries=1" But I still see the same issue. Even I tried adding Spring @Transactional annotation on method level as well. Anything else you feel I might be missing.  And I observed one more issue that after adding transactionIdPrefix, outputChannel.send is sending same message twice.

Comment: Don't put code/config in comments; it's unreadable; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. As I said, consumers must be configured with `read_committed`; if that's not the problem, edit the question to show all your config.

Comment: Updated the question. Currently there is no consumer on the output topic. But I'll make sure when I'll add consumer I'll configured with read_committed.

Comment: `>Message still sent to the outbound channel. ` Of course it is; you send it before the `acknowledge()` call. However, the transaction will roll back and mark the sent record as rolled back.

Comment: So you mean to say still the messages sent to outbound channel with record as rollback, read_commited Consumer will not consume that message. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks Gary. One more query please. I observed after adding  transactionIdPrefix, outboundChannel start sending same message twice. If I remove transactionIdPrefix then it send one message only. Any pointers on this?

Comment: I don't see how that is possible; please provide evidence.

Comment: I'll update here. BTW with current implementation message is still sending into outbound topic with record as rollback. Is there any way that in case there is any error, message will not get sent to the outbound topic but it should go to some error topic after 3 retry? Please let me know if there is any right way to handle this.

Comment: See `enableDlq` https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties

Comment: Thanks that helped. I could see messages are going into Dlq topic now. But whenever I restart the application same message going into Dlq topic again. Looks like message offset is not getting commited in the main topic. I explicitly mark autoCommitOnError as true. Configuration updated in the main question

Comment: Try enabling DEBUG logging to follow the commit logic.

Comment: looks like autoCommitOffset true doesn't work for me. but manual acknowledgement worked. Thanks Gary for your help